# building complicated relationships in a relational database

Tags: database, sqlalchemy, relational-database, relationship, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a general question about relational database design. I have a large list of objects from a table. These objects are classified with three descriptor classes. There is distributor1, distributor2 and distributor3. To describe one object one always builds a triplet of these descriptors.

For example assume that descriptor1 is colour, descriptor2 is size and descriptor3 is weight. For each object I would build a triplet which describes that object.
In my case I have thousands of entries for each descriptor. So I build a table for each descriptor. How can I now build a tripled and relate that to an object in the object table?

If there would be only one such tripled for each object, I could just store the three descriptor ids in each object as a foreign key, but let's assume that each object can have 0 or many such triplets.

I am using sqlalchemy, but I am happy to do the coding myself, I am just looking for keywords to look for in the documentation, since so far I could not find much.

My solution would be to create another table with three descriptor ids and and object id. Is that the way to go? 
I could also store a string with tripled of descriptor ids in each object... but that seems to go very much against the principle of relational databases...

Comment: If every object will always have these three values, I'd create one new table with: obect_id, attr1_id, attr2_id, attr3_id.  However if there was going to be any variance, I'd store each attribute and it's value in a different row from the others.

Comment: what do you mean with 'However if there was going to be any variance, I'd store each attribute and it's value in a different row from the others'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's rarely a perfect design for all scenarios.  What you've described would work well, if you know that you'll never need another attribute and you'll always lookup that row by using all three attributes.  It depends on your use case, but those are pretty limiting assumptions.

Adding more attributes or looking up records by 1 or 2 attributes instead of all 3 is when Lucas's suggestion of adding additional columns that can be indexed is more flexible.  The ability to define an arbitrary set of columns within a non-clustered index is where the relational db tends to get a lot of it's search performance/flexibility.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Indeed there are cases where I need 2 or 1 descriptor instead of a triplet. I am not sure however, how your solution with adding columns would work? Adding columns to the object table? how many columns and how would they look like?

Comment: Consider the object table that Lucas described:

ObjectTable
  Object_Id
  Attr1_ID
  Attr2_ID
  Attr3_ID

Now consider different select statements against this Object table:
Q1: Select * from Object where Attr1_ID = 5
or 
Q2: Select * from Object where Attr1_ID = 5 and Attr2_ID = 2

You can add as many attribute columns to the Object table as you desire.

The two select clauses might use a single index
Index_A (Attr1_ID,Attr2_ID)

But creating an index that was dedicating to just Q1 would be smaller and would be cheaper to bring into RAM than Index_A.
Index_B(Attr1_ID)